# Copying and pasting images across websites works on most browsers, but not on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, iphone

I have implemented image copying and pasting functionality between two websites using JavaScript. The code works flawlessly on most web browsers, but it fails on iOS devices, specifically Safari on iPhone and iPad.

Here's the code I used:

```
const data = await fetch(imgUrl);
const blob = await data.blob();
navigator.clipboard.write([
    new ClipboardItem({
        [blob.type]: blob,
    }),
]);


const clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.read();
for (const item of clipboardContents) {
    const blob = item.getType("image/png");
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var dataURL = event.target.result;
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            $("#sclogo_paste_img").addClass('whitebg');
            $("#sclogo_paste_img").html(img);
            $('#clogo').html($("#sclogo_paste_img").html());
            $("#sclogo_paste_img").prepend('<span class="file_remove sclogo_file_remove"><img src="wp-content/uploads/2023/08/delete.png"></span>');
        };
        img.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

How can I make this code compatible with iOS Safari?